# “An unhandled error has occurred.” when using Identity scaffold elements in a Blazor application

Tags: asp.net-core, identity, blazor, scaffold

1. Created a *Blazor WebAssembly 3.2.0 Preview 3* application template using *Individual User Accounts* and the *ASP.NET Core hosted* parameter
2. At this point, everything starts up correctly and the standard Blazor application is displayed.
3. Added scaffold *Registration* and *Login* pages
4. The application starts without errors, but the display template stops working and a message appears the message *“An unhandled error has occurred"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From  this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19779)

> The Identity scaffolder adds a wwwroot folder to the Server project with the default set of styles and other assets for the default Identity UI. These styles then override the styles that come from the Client project. In particular, both the Client and Server projects end up with a css/site.css.

You have the following two options：

1. Change the name of `site.css` of wwwroot folder in  Blazor Server project.
2. Remove the wwwroot folder in  Blazor Server project.